# Bootstrap on mobile: two column on horizontal view

Tags: mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

is there a way on bootstrap, in mobile view, to have one column listing on vertical view and, on phone rotation, two column on horizontal view, using the usual col-xs-xx methodology?

I'm not able to find a way.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The column breakpoints are based on your device viewport in pixels. You could modify this breakpoints with bootstraps generator, less, scss or harder with hacking the bootstrap core css. You could also generate additional breakpoints with less/scss.

You could also do some magic with jquery "on orientationchange" and toggle some classes when viewport width is greater as viewport height. ;)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Below I posted a working example in order to help other people for the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

By default Bootrap has this configuration:

```
< 768px   = -xs- prefix
>= 768px  = -sm- prefix
>= 992px  = -md- prefix
>= 1200px  = -lg- prefix
```

Using this standards, Bootstrap considers mobile portrait and landscape both as `-xs-` devices.

You could override (using less or sass/scss) this variables:

```
@screen-sm-min
@screen-md-min
@screen-lg-min
```

to achieve what you are looking.

For example you could change `@screen-sm-min` to 480px to target vertical device with `-xs-` prefix and horizontal device with `-sm-` prefix.

Mind you that in this way you lose the possibility to target portrait tablet.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to cakebake suggestion, this is a working example

https://jsfiddle.net/mud16c60/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="extra">
        <div id="switch1" class="col-xs-12">
            left
        </div>
        <div id="switch2" class="col-xs-12">
            right
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="orientation"></div>

$(window).on("orientationchange",function(event){
    $( "#orientation" ).text( "This device is in " + event.orientation + " mode!" );
    if(event.orientation=="landscape")
    {
        $("#extra [id^='switch']").removeClass( "col-xs-12" );
        $("#extra [id^='switch']").addClass( "col-xs-6" );
    }
    else if(event.orientation=="portrait")
    {
        $("#extra [id^='switch']").removeClass( "col-xs-6" );
        $("#extra [id^='switch']").addClass( "col-xs-12" );
    }
});
$( window ).orientationchange();
```